# Filling up an array field inside a struct

Tags: c, arrays, struct

Ok I am putting the whole struct here, its specification of a protocol named openflow that is implemented in some of industrial switches , so the struct is like:

```
struct ofp_packet_in {
    struct ofp_header header;
    uint32_t buffer_id;     /* ID assigned by datapath. */
    uint16_t total_len;     /* Full length of frame. */
    uint16_t in_port;       /* Port on which frame was received. */
    uint8_t reason;         /* Reason packet is being sent (one of OFPR_*) */
    uint8_t pad;
    uint8_t data[0];        /* Ethernet frame, halfway through 32-bit word,
                               so the IP header is 32-bit aligned.  The
                               amount of data is inferred from the length
                               field in the header.  Because of padding,
                               offsetof(struct ofp_packet_in, data) ==
                               sizeof(struct ofp_packet_in) - 2. */
};
OFP_ASSERT(sizeof(struct ofp_packet_in) == 20);
```

now I have to fill up some data in the last field that is -`uint8_t data[0]` which can be varied and info is gathered from the length field inside the header. I have to construct a packet in, and for that data has to be put in. Please take a look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to use a dynamic allocation and copy the contents.

Something like:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

void foo(void) {
  struct some_struct *container = malloc(sizeof(struct some_struct) + 100);
  if (!container) {
    // handle out-of-memory situation
  }
  memcpy(container->data, some_data, 100);
}
```

Comment: My answer applies to your changed structure. Replace `+100` by the size you need, and use `container->data` to fill the data in.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do this. It won't fit! The array in the struct is 0 chars long and you're trying to stuff a 100-char array into it.

If, for some reason, you are certain that the memory after the struct is available, e.g. you just malloc'ed it like this:

```
some_struct *foo = (some_struct*)malloc(sizeof(some_struct) + 100);
```

Then you can do this:

```
memcpy(foo->data, some_data, 100);
```

It's hideous, and probably still undefined behaviour, but I've seen APIs that require this (Windows?).

Comment: That's not valid, you didn't allocate any storage for foo.data => undefined behavior

Answer (score 0):

you can't.

You defined the size of **some_struct.data** to be **0**, meaning it cannot hold any items.
If all you want is to copy max. 100 items into it, then you can define the size statically:

```
struct some_struct { 
char data[100];  // some_struct.data has room for up to 100 characters 
};
```